# Finding an internship - resources for a middle school student?

Tags: cv, physics, online-resource, internship

I am interested in the fields of mathematics, physics, and computer science (broad, I know) but if I had the ideal internship it would be in a quantum computing lab. Really, though, I'm looking for anything this summer. While this may seem like a somewhat normal thing (student looking for internship) I have a small problem in that I'm in middle school.

I am in 8th grade, and I am old enough to legally work (just getting that out of the way). I am located in the United States. I have taught myself some physics and mathematics (the basics of calculus and linear algebra, etc) and I have been told I learn quickly. I'm willing to work hard and do just about anything, but I'd like to start getting experience with research in a lab. (If you need any further information, please ask.)

What are some resources I can use to find an internship? Also, I've read that you're supposed to put together a resume/cv, but reading about it it seems a bit difficult to do when the only things you've done are K-8th grade and some personal projects.

If this is off-topic, I apologize; this seemed the place to ask.

Comment: Yes this is offtopic (mostly professional academic questions), but you should start with your school guidance counselor or contact a counselor at the high school you will be attending next year. He/she should have access to resource information. You should also check with your local university. Many have summer STEM programs that are a great place to get started with interesting projects. Michigan Tech, University of Colorado are two specifically that I know of but wouldn't' be surprised if more had outreach programs as well.

Comment: Also look into the various colloquiums that your local university might offer. Many times they are open to the public so you can get a taste of current research (CU had a physics colloquium targeted at high school students for a while). Don't get discouraged if most of what you find are more geared as "camps". You probably won't find gainful employment as a middle school student.

Comment: Have you looked into the science olympiads?

Comment: Try asking some of the people [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/school/how-school-works/instructors), in particular Ahlin and Zucker who I know so feel free to say that I suggested you write them.

Comment: @MarkoKarbevski, looking at them, I don't think it's quite what I want, but thank you, I'll keep that in mind

Comment: @scrappedcola, thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro, thank you so much! Just to be clear, do you mean to ask the question I asked here, or to ask for some sort of internship?

Comment: A bunch of universities offer programs to high school students to do a project in a lab over the summer. If you live in NJ - NY area I know Rockefeller and Princeton have such things.

Comment: I meant for you to ask the question you asked here. For the two I suggested, both their school aged backgrounds (includes science, not just math) and their later backgrounds (both have taught in brick-and-mortar high schools, not just online) probably make them about as knowledgeable as most anyone for advice like this. Of course, I'm sure they'd mention any possible such internship where they are, but I doubt they would have something suitable for you at the present time. Sorry for the tardy reply -- I was offline all weekend.